# Remove CSS rule with !important property

Tags: javascript, css

In order to "null" pseudo elements content I use :

```
  var rule = document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js * .vjs-icon-placeholder:before {content: " "!important;}', 0);
```

I works only if "!important" property specified.
In some situation I need to restore original pseudo elements content.
I tried:
`document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(rule)`;
That doesn't work. Is there is a way to restore original content?

Comment: But why don't you add a special class to your element, and write a CSS rule that applies to this class? Then you just have to toggle the class. That's how it's done, not by writing code in the existing CSS using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another class to the element that sets the content to another value.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  document.querySelector(".vjs-icon-placeholder").classList.toggle("nocontent");
});
```

```css
.vjs-icon-placeholder:before{
  content: "This is some before text";
  display: block;
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.vjs-icon-placeholder.nocontent:before {
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="vjs-icon-placeholder">
This is a div.
</div>
<button>
Toggle Content
</button>
```

If all video-js elements have a common ancestor (you can use the body for this purpose), you can toggle the nocontent class just on that ancestor instead, i.e. `#ancestor.nocontent .video-js * .vjs-icon-placeholder:before{content: " "}` and `document.querySelector("#ancestor").classList.toggle("nocontent")`.

Comment: The problem is, that there are many(~10) different elements. Each of them has unique content (that's why - .video-js *). May be loop?

Comment: @Serg Just write this in your CSS: `.video-js.nocontent * .vjs-icon-placeholder:before{content: " "}`. Then just toggle the `nocontent` class on all elements with the class `video-js`.

Comment: @Serg If all video-js elements have a common ancestor (you can use the body for this purpose), you can toggle the nocontent class just on that ancestor instead, i.e. `#ancestor.nocontent .video-js * .vjs-icon-placeholder:before{content: " "}` and `document.querySelector("#ancestor").classList.toggle("nocontent")`.

Comment: document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js.nocontent * :before {content: " "!important;}', 0) and following document.querySelector(".video-js *").classList.toggle("nocontent") - does nothing

Comment: Don't use insertRule. Just edit your CSS as I have shown above.

Comment: Get it works by looping through all video-js with classList.toggle("nocontent")

Comment: Inserted in CSS - works perfectly without looping.Thanks.

Comment: @Serg No problem.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, because when you remove the rule, it removes the `content` from the HTML,

I believe the best method would be to get the `content` first and then reassign.

```js
var prev = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('..vjs-icon-placeholder'), ':before'
).getPropertyValue('content')

let prevContent = prev.substring(1,prev.length-1) //to remove the quotes from start and end.

var rule = document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js * .vjs-icon-placeholder:before {content: " "!important;}', 0);
```

Now wherever you decide to revert back to previous content.

```js
var rule = document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.video-js * .vjs-icon-placeholder:before {content: '+prevContent+'!important;}', 0);
```

Comment: That the problem - it doesn't remove it from HTML. Inspector still shows  content: " "!important;

Comment: Ohhh!
So You may create a selector and then change the CSS using JS.